# How to send different mix to 3 separate headphones?

Tags: headphones, mixer, monitoring, console, aux-sends

I would like to be able to send different mixes to different headphones.

I initially did this by putting it through the Aux sends, but this comes out in mono and suffers from a large amount of clipping.

What do i have to do to send multiple mixes in stereo?
Do I need more gear?
Can this be achieved with the Behringer mx2442a?

I thought about buying a headphone amp like the Behringer 4400, but this will only allow me to send the same signal to 4 headphones - I would like to send different signals to each headphone. I would rather not have to replace the mixer at this early stage if possible.

The actual setup is 2 guitars mic'd, 1 vocal mic, 7 drum mics. I'd like to create 3 different headphone mixes from these.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you do, you'll definitely need some kind of headphone amp(s) to properly drive the headsets' low impedance. With such amplification, the aux sends should be just fine, they shouldn't feature more clipping than the master output.

Of course, the aux sends will only me mono; IMHO that should always be ok for monitoring (or in fact better: I once tried using my in-ears in stereo for a while (myself on right ear mostly), but found that it was not helpful at all for overall orientation.

Comment: Yes to @leftroundabout - mono is best for clarity and precision of monitors. Clipping is from impedance or gain structure issues. Buy multiple headphone amps, one for each aux, they don't each have to have 4 outputs, just look for something more or less portable and durable as these won't be confined to your desk (usually you plug the headphones straight into the amp, while running a longer line from your console to the amp wherever the player is)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that console has 4 sub-mix busses. Which means you can create two stereo sub-mixes.

On the individual channel strip, you'd click the 1-2 or 3-4 buttons (or both), and then use the strip's pan pot to place the track in the stereo space of that sub-mix.

Over on the sub-mix output, you'd make sure you've got 1 and 2 hard panned left and right, respectively.  Same for 3 and 4.

Then just use the sub-mix outputs to send to your cans.

Of course, this only gets you two separate mixes.  I suppose, if you didn't need the main outs for some reason, you could use that for the third mix.

Comment: Or you could produce 4 mono mixes, sending each into a separate headphone amp.  Setting the levels for a given headphones is tricky because of having to use both level and pan to control the level.